# How to enable bootstrap dropdown buttons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The drop down button do nothing when clicked. In the console I can see that the `.open` class does get added to the button upon click, but it is instantly removed.

HTML:

```
<div class = 'btn-group'>
    <button class = 'btn dropdown-toggle' data-toggle = 'dropdown'>Radio Station <span class = 'caret'></span></button>
    <ul class = 'dropdown-menu'>
        <li><a href="#">WKAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double check all of your dependencies. Make sure you have all of the appropriate CSS, JS files.

**make sure you have these dependencies:**

```
<head>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Your html:**

```
<div class = 'btn-group'>
    <button class = 'btn dropdown-toggle' data-toggle = 'dropdown'>Radio Station <span class = 'caret'></span></button>
    <ul class = 'dropdown-menu'>
        <li><a href="#">WKAQ</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

Here is a working example with your HTML:

http://jsfiddle.net/JLXN7/18/

Comment: The fiddle is not working anymore. At least the javascript is outdated or something like that.

Comment: Looks like Twitter changed the path to their assets. It should work now though.

Comment: Also note, you can find these under "External Resources" in the fiddle.